# Prevent family overriding organ donation wishes

Tags: united-kingdom

In the UK, the NHS generally allows families of the deceased to override their expressed wishes to donate their organs.

Is there any legal mechanism whereby a person could prevent this from happening such that their organs were donated regardless of their family's consent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

Your information is slightly [wrong](https://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/helping-you-to-decide/about-organ-donation/faq/consent/). Families do not have the *legal* right to override the wishes of the prospective donor, however, the ultimate legal decision maker (where donor consent has been given) is the medical practitioner. The donor or the family can influence that decision but they can’t dictate it. Most doctors will not harvest in opposition to the family’s wishes but that is a matter that is legally within the doctor’s discretion.

Comment: As an aside, if the doctor does go ahead with organ donation against the families wishes, regardless of the donors wishes, then that would commonly result in a complaint by the family to either the hospital or the GMC, which for a doctor is a very very serious matter.  With the GMC, it doesn't matter what the legality of the situation is, the GMC can find against the doctor for many reasons and impose sanctions (up to and including loss of license to practice).